# Ориентирован вверх, наверх

Tags: семантика

Возможны ли сочетания "орентирован на(в)верх, вниз" или только "ориентирован вертикально"?

Стрелка ориентирована наверх. Ракета в космодроме была, естественно, ориентирована наверх.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, такая конструкция вполне возможна. В Корпусе русского языка много примеров конструкций вроде "*ориентирован вдоль линии*", "*ориентирован на север*", "*ориентирован в сторону моря*".

Вот еще похожий пример использования [в толковом словаре](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dmitriev/3175/%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C#sel=11:1,11:43):

*"Если какой-либо географический объект ориентирован в каком-то направлении, значит, он занимает определённое положение относительно частей света, он вытянут в этом направлении; Озеро ориентировано с запада-юго-запада на восток-северо-восток".*

Только все же, наверное, не "в космодроме", а "на космодроме".